# What does [Edit removed during grace period] mean?

Tags: support, editing, edit-history

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098034/calculating-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-1n1) a couple of days ago and today I saw that it was [edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1098034/revisions) by some user.

When I clicked on the Revisions, instead of the revision, I saw this:

> [Edit removed during grace period]

I've never seen this before. What does it mean?

Comment: I edited your question, replacing "his" by "their". Then I edited again, replacing "their" back by "his". You can see the effect in the [revision history](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/19222/revisions).

Comment: As with many things concerning the underlying architecture, [see MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180564/214632).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The user made an edit, then before five minutes (the "grace period") passed reverted it ([but not via the "rollback" feature](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/19223/revisions)). In general if you do multiple edits within the five minutes window they only count as one. If the net result is that nothing changed, there's no difference to show in the revisions window, but the system still records the fact that there was an edit.